# Retrofit call enqueue doesn't reach onResponse or onFailure

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I know this is a common question, but I did all of them, still no resolved. In my **MainActivity**, I had a call from an **ServerService.java**, like this:

```
String randomNumber = serverService.contactServer();
```

In the **ServerService.java**, the **contactServer()** will call the method which contains the .enqueue:

```
  public String contactServer() {     
    return requestServerService();
}
```

And the **requestServerService()** contains the code:

```
 public String requestServerService() {

    Call<RequestAttributes> call = new RetrofitConfig().getServiceRequester().requestRandomNumber();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<RequestAttributes>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RequestAttributes> call, Response<RequestAttributes> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("Err", "Err: " + response.code());
            } else {
                RequestAttributes requestAttributes = response.body();
                returnedValue = requestAttributes.getRandomNumber();
                Log.d("jsonAnswer", "O numero aleatorio é: " + returnedValue);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RequestAttributes> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Fail", "Failed: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    }); return returnedValue;
```

The **error** is the **returnedValue** returns null. I tried debbuging, but even it doesn't reach onReponse. I know the problem must be because .enqueue is asynchronous, but how can I resolve this problem and return the request to the **mainActivity**?

The **config** of Retrofit:

```
  public RetrofitConfig() {

    this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("localhost:3000/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

}

public ServiceRequester getServiceRequester() {
    return this.retrofit.create(ServiceRequester.class);
}
```

The **POJO**:

```
public class RequestAttributes {


@SerializedName("randomNumber")
private String randomNumber;

public String getRandomNumber() {
    return randomNumber;
}

public void setRandomNumber(String randomNumber) {
    this.randomNumber = randomNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RequestAttributes{" +     
            ", randomNumber='" + randomNumber + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

And the **request**:

```
 @GET("api/requestRandomNumber")
 Call<RequestAttributes> requestRandomNumber();
```

The **JSON answer** if I request via browser:

```
{"randomNumber":"u845gq"}
```

Comment: show what is your json from backhand ?

Comment: share your base url class

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: what is your base url

Comment: @SandeepMalik i had updated the post with all your questions. The base url is localhost, but i changed to work with the smartphone. This is okay. Thank you!

Comment: @JoãoVitorBrasil It's not about callbacks. When you call `enqueue` retrofit execute the call in another thread so the return statement `return returnedValue;` will always return the initial value which is `null` in your case.

Comment: Check this link to know more about [Multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm)

Comment: @IbrahimDisouki I got your point, thanks. But can you give me an example how to run the onRespost before the return?

Comment: @JoãoVitorBrasil I'm going to add an answer.

Comment: @IbrahimDisouki thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass callbacks from your `MainActivity` to `contactServer()` method

```
        serverService.contactServer(new Callback<RequestAttributes>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RequestAttributes> call, Response<RequestAttributes> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("Err", "Err: " + response.code());
            } else {
                RequestAttributes requestAttributes = response.body();
                String returnedValue = requestAttributes.getRandomNumber();
                // Do what you want here with returnedValue. You are in the activity thread(MainThread or UIThread) for example someTextView.setText(returnedValue);
                Log.d("jsonAnswer", "O numero aleatorio é: " + returnedValue);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RequestAttributes> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Fail", "Failed: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Then make it `void` method, pass the callback to `requestServerService()` method

```
public void contactServer(Callback<RequestAttributes> callback) {
    requestServerService(callback);
}
```

Then implement `requestServerService()` method like this:

```
public void requestServerService(Callback<RequestAttributes> callback) {

    Call<RequestAttributes> call = new RetrofitConfig().getServiceRequester().requestRandomNumber();

    call.enqueue(callback);
}
```

Comment: awesome, it worked! Thank you so much! Just one more question:  Is possible to do the callbacks in the serverService class?

Comment: how can I set the returnedValue to an global variable?

Comment: You can do this in `onResponse()` method

Comment: I tried this, but i'm not able to obtain the value in another class. Is this possible to do?